# I have a table id of 4000 thousand I want to put the last number in @a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @a Int,

SET @a = (SELECT TOP 1 UserTableID + 1 AS FisNo 
          FROM ET_MalzemeveHareketleri  
          ORDER BY UserTableID DESC) 

SELECT @a
```

This is the code I have a table id of 4000 thousand rows, I want to load the last number into the `@a` variable.

Comment: Do you simply want `SELECT MAX(UserTableID) + 1 ...`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it gives an error again, when set @a= it underlines the set in red

Comment: @GarethD When set @a= it underlines the set in red

Comment: And what is the error message? Does the code actually execute despite the error indicated by the IDE?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have comma in wrong place (`DECLARE @a Int,`), that's all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
declare @a Int;

select @a = colname
from table
where ...
;
```

Comment: This will work, but will also retrieve every row from the table, and arbitrarily assign one of them to the variable. It is inefficient and non-deterministic. At the least it needs an order by to ensure the correct value is assigned, but since only one row is needed, it should probably also use `TOP (1)` to avoid retrieving redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
declare @a Int;

----IF Identity is mentained as 1-1

SELECT @a=(SELECT TOP 1 UserTableID FROM ET_MalzemeveHareketleri  order by UserTableID desc);

----IF Identity is not mentained

SELECT @a=(SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ET_MalzemeveHareketleri'));

select @a
```